# IE8 scale image to fit container with ms-filter

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm using following function to append to each div the `-ms-filter` property to scale up the background image to fit its container size in IE8:

```
    $('.news-product .product-image').each(function(){
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url("','').replace('")','');

        if(typeof bg !== 'none'){
            $(this).css({
                "-ms-filter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+bg+"', sizingMethod='scale')"
            });
        }
    });
```

It adds the filter and the sizingMethod but not the src attribute.
If I add it manually it works...

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm figured it out. When adding `"filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+bg+"', sizingMethod='scale')"` it works...
Very strange! I've thought that IE8 only requires `-ms-filter`.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying pretty much the same thing. It was being added to the element's inline CSS, but `-ms-filter` was being converted to `MsFilter`. I was looking at a way to fix it, but instead tried simply `filter` and it worked.